# Error using file/prefs api

Tags: trigger.io

Executing the following code:

```
    $.each(video.videos, function(k, v) {
        forge.prefs.get("video-"+k, function(file) {
            console.log(file, (file));
            if (file) {
                forge.file.URL(file, function (url) {
                    video.videos[k].source = url;
                    console.log("video found: " + k + " " + url);
                });
            } else if (get) {
                forge.file.saveURL(v.url, function(file){
                    console.log("video saved: " + k + " " + v.url);
                    forge.prefs.set("video-"+k, file, function(){
                        download.get_video();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Results in the following:

```
error occurred: file:///var/mobile/Applications/91521D1A-B4B6-4AAB-9960-F2AD747F1A49/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-6AF5A9D3-5267-4327-889A-8EE004DF7779/forge/all.js:2: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a({message:f.toString()})')
```

The error appears to be with forge.prefs.get() as Catalyst shows the api call to be pending indefinitely. Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the inclusion of the JSON3 js library, I think this must have broken the forge interpreter thats used to translate the results of api calls, by overwriting the JSON method perhaps.